# Any way to override .NET Windows Service Name without recompiling?

Tags: .net, windows-services

I have a windows service executable that I know is written in .NET which I need to install under a different service name to avoid a conflict.  The install doesn't provide anyway to specify a service name.  If I only have access to the binary, is there anyway to override the service name when I install it with installutil?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Do you have to use InstallUtil? Here are the commands to do what you want using sc:

```
sc create MyService binPath= "MyService.exe" DisplayName= "MyService"  
sc description MyService "My description"
```

Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want -- however I can't get it to work.  I just keep getting a "usage" message.

Comment: My problem was that there apparently *must* be a space between the equal sign and the binPath value, e.g. sc create ahSchedulerService binPath= "MyService.exe", not sc create ahSchedulerService binPath="MyService.exe".

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that. Sorry for giving you a bad example.

Comment: When I used the SC command to create a service instance, I found that I had to put the entire path before the EXE name. Before running SC, I had changed my command prompt directory to be the same as the EXE, thinking that would be enough, but it wasn’t. When I tried to start the service, I got an error saying “system cannot find the file specified”. So the SC command has to have a parameter like: binPath= "C:\whatever\servieName.exe"

Comment: When running from `PowerShell` window, make sure to use `sc.exe` instead of `sc`, otherwise `PowerShell` thinks you mean `Set-Content`.

Answer (score 30):

It is not true that InstallUtil doesn't allow you to configure the service name.  I do it all the time like this

```
InstallUtil.exe /servicename="<service name>" "<path to service exe>"
```

Comment: if you already have a service with same name as exe, it will give error `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified service already exists`. I was trying to install 2 instances of same service and naming them differently. 

Use sc create methods given in below answers

Comment: Does not work. Gives an error that my service already exists.

Comment: Works if you have a project installer and override the install and uninstall like in @Volodymyrs answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25259719/169714

Comment: does not work on a default installer created from Visual studio

Comment: If I change parameter "servicename" to "name" it works for me.

Comment: Received this Error: An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified service already exists

Any way around?

Answer (score 27):

1. Add project installer to your service
2. Add method to get CustomService name

   ```
   private void RetrieveServiceName() 
   {
       var serviceName = Context.Parameters["servicename"];
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceName))
       {
           this.SomeService.ServiceName = serviceName;
           this.SomeService.DisplayName = serviceName;
       }
   }
   ```
3. call on install and uninstall

   ```
   public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
   {
      RetrieveServiceName();
     base.Install(stateSaver);
   }


   public override void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)

   {
      RetrieveServiceName();
      base.Uninstall(savedState);
   }
   ```
4. `installutil /servicename=”My Service [SysTest]” d:\pathToMyService\Service.exe`

[Source](http://journalofasoftwaredev.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/multiple-instances-of-same-windows-service/)

Comment: This was very useful, I did have to recompile my service executable to get it work once I added this code, that wasn't an issue for me.

Comment: taken from the source link but incase... You need to change the “someService” to the ServiceInstaller name. It’s probably ServiceInstaller1 as that is the default.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

This exactly worked for me!

I hope someone can use this.

Comment: image is broken

Comment: dedicated to copy paste: 
`sc create FooService_v666 binPath= "c:\path\foo\bar.exe"  DisplayName= "foo bar service" start= auto`

Answer (score 2):

Try installing your service with sc.exe. A quick search will yield lots documentation. With that tool it's easy to modify existing services and/or add new ones -- including names.

Edit: I install my .NET services with this tool.