# How to install a Windows service (via installutil) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, command

My code:

```
Process kurulum1 = new Process();
kurulum1.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Visual Studio 2017\Visual Studio Tools\Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017.lnk";

 kurulum1.StartInfo.Arguments = "cd C:\\Users\\stajyer3\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\TestWindowsService\\TestWindowsService\\bin\\Debug InstallUtil.exe "TestWindowService.exe"  ";

kurulum1.Start();

kurulum1.WaitForExit();
```

Not Working

> Error:
>
> [ERROR:parse_cmd.bat] Invalid command line argument: 'cd'. Argument
>   will be ignored. [ERROR:parse_cmd.bat] Invalid command line argument:
>   'C:\Users\stajyer3\Documents\Visual'. Argument will be ignored.
>   [ERROR:parse_cmd.bat] Invalid command line argument: 'Studio'.
>   Argument will be ignored. [ERROR:parse_cmd.bat] Invalid command line
>   argument:
>   '2017\Projects\TestWindowsService\TestWindowsService\bin\Debug'.
>   Argument will be ignored.
>
> ---
>
> ** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.0.26430.14
>   ** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
>   ********************************************************************** [ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] *** VsDevCmd.bat encountered errors. Environment
>   may be incomplete and/or incorrect. ***

Comment: could you please format your code?

Comment: I've reformatted your post for you. Please consider doing so yourself in the future, to make it more readable. The preview is there for a reason.

Comment: @MaviLe tell us what you want the code to do, are you trying to run command prompt, start "Debug InstallUtil.exe" run "TestWindowService.exe" we can't fix your code for you unless we know what you want the code to do

Comment: @MikeT I want to install the windows service named TestWindowService.exe in c #

Answer (score 3):

you have made many mistakes here , with out knowing your objective its very difficult to say which is the worst

1. `ProcessStartInfo.FileName` should be the file you want to execute
   not a start menu shortcut
2. `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` is a command line argument not a
   command
3. the command you are using seems to be an attempt to change the
   working directory this should be done with
   `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`
4. the strings you are using are broken because you are exiting the
   strings by using " but then you carry the string on, so i must
   assume you mean the " to be inside the string in which case you need
   to delimit them with \ this would then look like `"he said \"delimit
   your strings\" "`though if you are using the @ notation then the 
   delimiter becomes "" not \"
5. arguments are space separated strings so if your arguments contain
   spaces such as long form filenames then you need to surround them
   with quotes " so `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "a b c:\\temp";` will pass the args "a", "b" and "c:\temp" to the executing program but  `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "a literal string arg";` would pass each word as as separate argument `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "\"a literal string arg\"";` and this will pass in a single arg with the entire string

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the path in quotes (and escape the quotes around the filename)

```
kurulum1.StartInfo.Arguments = "cd \"C:\\Users\\stajyer3\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\TestWindowsService\\TestWindowsService\\bin\\Debug InstallUtil.exe\" \"TestWindowService.exe\"  ";
```

Comment: you are perfectly correct, not sure why the down vote, they have made other errors beside this one but you have covered the OP's posted errors

Comment: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: @MaviLe thats your Filename not the args

Comment: How can I fix ?

Comment: @MaviLe read the comments on the question  mjwills has asked you to clarify what you want to happen so that we can help you

Comment: @MikeT I want to setup windows service in c #

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl:

```
var kurulum1 = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe",
        WorkingDirectory =
            "C:\\Users\\stajyer3\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\TestWindowsService\\TestWindowsService\\bin\\Debug",
        Arguments = "TestWindowService.exe"
    }
};
kurulum1.Start();
kurulum1.WaitForExit();
```

There is no need to involve the `Developer Command Prompt` - you can just invoke `installutil` directly.

Comment: The transaction is not occurring and I can not see the error

Comment: How is your code running? Is it a command line app? A web-app? Something else? Can you copy and paste your class into https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and `Share` a link so I can check your code and make sure there isn't a typo?

Comment: I'm new on stackoverflow.

Comment: I want to see if a windows service setup program called TestWindowsService is running in services at c # form application

Comment: I can not see installutil.exe running and shutting down

Comment: Why do you need to see that? Are you worried it isn't working? If so, uninstall it yourself (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22373062/34092) and then run my code. If it is there, my code must have installed it successfully.

Comment: I can not see the windows service in the services I want to install @mjwills