# How to install window service using installer in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dll

I am having trouble in finalizing my window service.As my logic works fine in console application.But the problem is:

**How to add installer and installutil.exe in the project?**

Answer (score 2):

Go to Visual Studio Command prompt, and type `installutil.exe <path to exe>`

Alternatively, installutil.exe is located under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe`

Note: Depending on your framework version, path to installutil.exe will change

Refer to this SO thread which has already an answer 
[Install a Windows service using a Windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164859/install-a-windows-service-using-a-windows-command-prompt)

Are you having trouble while adding installer in your project? Any detailed information will help us in guiding you in the right direction

Comment: When i install my *window service* it doesn't works and also not showing the service in **services.msc**

Comment: BTW, what type of project are you using? Windows Service or Console Application, Refer to this article in csharp-corner having step by step details on creating a windows service. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b7531b/create-simple-window-service-and-setup-project-with-installa/

Comment: I am using **Windows Service** and tested my code in *Console Application*.

Comment: that works fine in console application but not **Windows Service**

Comment: Ensure your user account have appropriate permissions to install the service, can you try installing the service from administrator account? or do you face any error while installing the service? if so, post the error to troubleshoot further

Comment: I have only one user account (_i.e Administrator_). On installation there is a admin privilege prompt. There is no error message.

Comment: Installation is all perfect. But the problem is: service is not performing it's task and also not showing in **services.msc**.

Comment: You can try writing a status to a log file in your windows service OnStart event to ensure the service is started. You can also check Windows EventViewer for any possible errors occurred while starting your service.