# How to build a Windows Service that connects to 80 SQL Servers every 30 seconds?

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, parallel-processing, windows-services

This is a purely theoretical post.

I am into SQL Server and PowerBuilder for more than 20 years.
Sometimes I mess with C# when things cannot be accomplished otherwise.

This time I was asked to investigate the following scenario using Windows Services C#, SQL Server and Threads.

We need to build a service which will need to get data in parallel* from 80 different SQL Servers every 30 seconds, create XMLs and post them - non stop.
They suggested I build a Service that creates 80 threads, each thread connect to its own SQL Server, has each own timer (of 30 seconds), retrieves the data, creates XMLs and sends.

Is this feasible from a technical point of view? Are there any suggestion of better implementing this scenario?

Thank you

*meaning that every 30 seconds each SQL Server must be revisited for the operation and not wait for a different SQL Server's operations to finish

Comment: I'm not a multithreading expert by any means, but 80 sounds like a very big number for threads. 
I'm also guessing some of the data might be cached, so I would suggest exploring change tracking. Also, Do you need to create an XML per database (or SQL Server instance), or a single XML from the data gathered from all databases?

Comment: Thank you. The XMLs are per SQL Server and are send to different vendors.

Comment: So basically you can think of it as 80 different services each reading its own data from its own database, creating its own XML and send it to its own customer, right?

Comment: Yes. That is the idea. We want one service to rule them all hahaha. So one physical machine, one codebase, 80 SQL Servers serviced.

Comment: Seems like a microservices-based solution is something worth exploring. There are tools to orchestrate such microsservice clusters (that's usually the work of DevOps to handle them, so I'm not familiar with how to do it exactly) but I know for a fact its possible to run multiple instances with different parameters on the same machine - so that's what I would probably explore.

Comment: I have a feeling such load might kill even a decent machine, how many rows are you fetching per 30 seconds per server? also, does it really have to be done every 30 secs, i hope you're not implementing a new self driving system

Comment: You don't need threads. Use tasks and `await` and stream all results, which will keep memory usage and context switching low. It might be feasible on a high powered server.

Comment: *"create XMLs and post them"* -- What do you mean by "post them"? Send POST HTTP requests to remote web servers?

Comment: How much time (in milliseconds) does it take on average to do the whole get/transform/send work for a single SQL server? 30 seconds divided by 80 servers is 375 milliseconds, so you might be on a tight schedule. We don't know how well your system can handle concurrency, so we might assume as well that it can't handle any at all, and that the 375 milliseconds is all you have to work with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The theory of this is not bad, but 80 is an arbitrarily large number, common scenarios like this involve 1 DB per customer and a process that brings metrics into a central repository. So if 80 represents your current customer base, then we should plan for that to scale beyond 80.

In practice, this task is not CPU intensive, the SQL load is handled on the server and all we end up doing is transmitting the data, which is another external protocol outside of the c# thread you'll be executing from. So multiple threads in this case is an expensive option... But it will simplify some of the code and ensure that each loop execution is independent of interruptions that might occur in other loops.

The problems lie in the way that HTTP and SQL connections work under the hood, I haven't tested SQL at this qty but HTTP will not allow you to have 80 parallel threads uploading at once, some of those threads will stall, others will be forced to wait.

- SQL should be ok to run all 80 concurrently because you are connecting to different servers.
- Last time I tried this overall throughput performance was significantly affected after 4 parallel uploads, and pretty much nothing worked after 8... but that was a few versions of .Net ago, this post matches my findings back then [Max number of concurrent HttpWebRequests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1361771/1690217)...

Queue or batched based transmission works much better for HTTP, especially if you are using [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0).

So the XML sending is better modelled using a single or limited number of *transmission queues*, to manage the possibility of multiple threads of the *readers* (we'll talk about that next) use a [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-7.0)

> `XmlMessage` in this example shouldn't hold the xml payload unless it is very small, otherwise this just hold whatever metadata you need to retrieve the XML file for transmission. *(Purely theoretical right ;)*
>
> Using `AutoReset = false` because this loop will restart the timer when the queue is empty, timer in this case is only to keep the process running without a `while(true)` style loop.

```
public static readonly ConcurrentQueue<XmlMessage> TransmissionQueue { get; } = new ();
private static System.Timers.Timer _transmissionTimer = new();
private static HttpClient _httpClient = new();
...
_transmissionTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;
_transmissionTimer.Elapsed += TransmissionTimer_OnElapsed;
_transmissionTimer.AutoReset = false;
_transmissionTimer.Start();
...

public async void TransmissionTimer_OnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: add Try/Catch error handling... 
    while(TransmissionQueue.TryDeQueue(out XmlMessage message))
    {
        var xmlData = ResolveXmlFromMessage(message);
        var content = new StringContent(xmlData, 
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");;
        await _httpClient.PostAsync(message.TargetUri, content);
    }

    // go into idle state, wait for more data
    _transmissionTimer.Start();
}
```

Due to the internals of HttpClient ([see Instancing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0#instancing)), if you need multiple transmission queues, it is better to explicitly declare them rather than creating the clients on demand. If your server can handle batched requests, or can ingest multiple XMLs or you can combine them on the client into one single file, then that will help this solution scale. Otherwise you might create 4-8 HttpClient instances and associated timers and queues to partition the processing.

There is a bit of fun when you get to partitioning, I would create a single entry point that either round robins the queues, or load balances the messages between the queues.

- If sequence of transmission is important and you have multiple queues, then you want to use an algorithm that always sends the data from the same server to the same queue

```
private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<XmlMessage> _transmissionQueue0 = new ();
private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<XmlMessage> _transmissionQueue1 = new ();
private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<XmlMessage> _transmissionQueue2 = new ();
private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<XmlMessage> _transmissionQueue3 = new ();
...

public static void Enqueue(XmlMessage message)
{
    // using int to simplify the logic, this might be DB or customer number
    int sequenceNumber = message.DatabaseSequenceNumber;
    switch(sequenceNumber % 4)
    {
        case 0: _transmissionQueue0.Enqueue(message); break;
        case 1: _transmissionQueue1.Enqueue(message); break;
        case 2: _transmissionQueue2.Enqueue(message); break;
        case 3: _transmissionQueue3.Enqueue(message); break;
    }
}
```

> You could encapsulate each queue, timer and http client in a single class definition, that will reduce the code duplication, but here for theory sake, we just want to highlight the basics.

So now we have established an asynchronous data transmission pipeline, next we need to deal with reading the data.

If you absolutely **MUST** ensure that a delay in one DB doesn't affect the other, then spin up a thread for each DB with it's own timer and reading logic. You should still be able to use the above `Enqueue` method to queue the messages for delivery.

However if the chance of failure is low, and the impact also low, then we could have a central timer for the 30 second interval and use parallel tasks to pull the data from the databases.

- With 80, I wouldn't use `await Task.WhenAll()`, [TPL](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/parallel-foreach-method-csharp/) will give you control over the degree of parallelism if/when it becomes a problem.
- [How to: Write a simple Parallel.ForEach loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)

```
List<DataSourceInfo> _sources = new(); 

private void DataSourceTimer_OnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(_sources, source =>
    {  
        XmlMessage xml = GetDataFromSource(source);
        Enqueue(xml);
    });
}
```

As you scale this, you might evolve into using cloud based timers and queues or atleast localised messaging bus queues outside of your c# runtime. The concepts remain the same, batch what you can, partition to ensure throughput without hogging resources.

---

Creating 80 threads to do it all might work, but it doesn't scale very well, not unless you can split those threads across multiple servers, which you have specifically said you don't want to do.

1 Db reader per server is not a good use of resources, but 1 server doing 80 might lead to race conditions. You might need to split the workload so that its doesn't to 20 per server deployment...

Another solution is to push this logic to the DB Servers themselves, either through SSIS or Jobs on the server. The management of this might get cumbersome very quickly though, you could script it via c# or powershell though...

Answer (score 0):

While I was reading your question, I asked myself to what extent your solution approach can be supported in the future.

I would have spontaneously thought of two options:

1. a PowerShell script which establishes the connection to a SQL server and queries the data. You could then store this script in a Windows timer job and set up your 80 jobs using parameters. This way you could also expand/deactivate/delete individual jobs
2. Develop one C# Windows service per SQL database and then register 80 Windows services using parameters.

In both cases, you could also distribute the load to different servers. If you already have experience with Docker or even Kubernetes, you could also use it to implement this use case.

Best regards

Comment: Thank you. One question though. Can a Windows Service be installed 80 times (with different params each) in one PC? The problem we are trying to solve is that till now we have one Windows Service for each SQL Server so we need 80 PCs to host them all.

Comment: You can install multiple Windows Service that do the same stuff. You only have to be aware to name them differently.

Comment: That is the problem. We need one codebase, one installer, one PC to serve everything. We = my employers :)

Comment: But that is not a problem. You can have one codebase which accepts input parameters. One installer is no problem, too. In Windows or LInux you can easily install services from within the cli and pass a name. With different names you can also run all these services on 1 PC if the PC has enough comupting, etc.
For Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164859/install-a-windows-service-using-a-windows-command-prompt
Example for Ubuntu: https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6

Comment: Powershell is slow, and cannot be multi-threaded or use `await` easily. 80 services means 80 processes which means a lot of context switching.

Comment: Thats why I suggested spanning up only one Scrip per Timer Job so that you don't need to multithread oder use async/await.